# Docker container - What does the option "--detach-keys Override the key sequence for detaching a container" mean?

Tags: docker, containers

There is very few precisions about this option after a googling,

Concretely I'm wondering what means "detach-key" and what is a "key sequence for detaching a container" please,

any hint would be great,
thanks

Answer (score 3):

The docs does not say, but the sequence is comma separated.  The default behaviour is
`--detach-keys="ctrl-p,ctrl-q"`.  This means nothing happens if you press just Control-P - it will wait for your next keypress.  If the next key press is Control-Q, you will detach from your interactive session, if you press anything else, both key presses are sent to your shell.  Detaching means the container will be kept running in the background, and you can re-attach later using `docker attach`.

You can observe this if you try to use Control-P instead of Up arrow to recall the previous command.  Nothing seems to happen, but if you press Control-E, you will see that the Control-P had effect.  As a long time Emacs and Happy Hacking Keyboard user (a keyboard without arrow keys), this is very annoying, so I have set

```
{
    "detachKeys": "ctrl-q,ctrl-q"
}
```

in my ~/.docker/config.json.

Comment: BLESS YOU. I thought this was a sticky cooked vs. uncooked terminal issue where the shell running inside Docker didn't see Control-P for some reason. I am delighted it's just a Docker "feature!"

Answer (score 1):

how are you? As it was explained here: [Docker Attach Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/)

> If you want, you can configure an override the Docker key sequence for
>   detach. This is useful if the Docker default sequence conflicts with
>   key sequence you use for other applications. There are two ways to
>   define your own detach key sequence, as a per-container override or as
>   a configuration property on your entire configuration.

--detach-keys="some sequence*" Option flag means Override key sequence for detaching a container, default key sequence is **not defined** but you can do it running a **CTRL-p CTRL-q** sequence.

Try it!